# How to use a xaml object in another class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have one class with a xaml which contains a label. I want to change content of this label from one different class.
for example i have a class mainwindow.xaml.cs with mainwindow.xaml and i want to handle the label of mainwindow.xaml from the newclass.cs.
How can i do this??

edit: i have this label in a grid and i want to change the content from another class:

`<Label Content="" Panel.ZIndex="1" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="16px" Name="lb1" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="250" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Top"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data binding and MVVM would be the most elegant solution.
But you can simply use code-behind.
Give the label a name `<Label x:Name="myLabel">` so you can access it in your code with that name like any other variable.
You can then pass this variable to your newclass.cs and change its properties there.

Comment: it helps me, but i don't know if i do this with the same way, in mainwindow class i create a new Label STATIC variable and make this equal with myLabel (from xaml), so i use the static variable in my newclass

Comment: @user1005633 no need to create static of the variable, rather pass it as a parameter to the method present in different class.
There if you change any property for this element, same will be reflected in the UI also.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is something like this, I'm not sure if it's the most logical thing to do but it works for me.

In your newclass.cs :

```
Class Newclass
{
     MainWindow main;


     public Newclass(MainWindow win)
     {
         main = win;
         main.label.content = "";
     }
}
```

and then in your mainwindow.xaml.cs:

```
Newclass class = new Newclass(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use binding - or even better binding with MVVM pattern and viewmodel first.

but nevertheless, when asking a question you should post some code